# Where is the best place to store supporting JSON on dynamic AJAX load?

Tags: javascript, html, json, model-view-controller

Scenario: I have an HTML page with a dynamic modal dialog. Links on the page open the dialog, but with different contents according to the clicked link. Dialog contents are loaded using an AJAX request, and include only the required HTML - no html or head tags, for example.

In the dialog, there is a 'Status' display, and a couple of date pickers (e.g. 'Activated' and 'Removed'). As the dates change, the Status should update to show the current status according to the dates. That I can do, no worries.

In the application I have an enum for the Status, and I want the JavaScript in this dialog to make use of the same list of statuses as the server-side app. I figure the MVC (server-side) should generate some JSON, listing the enum entries, for example:

```
{ "active": "Active", "removed", "Removed" }
```

Now the question! Where's the best place to put this JSON in the page, if it is loaded with the modal contents?
Here are some options I've considered:

- I could store it in a var in the head, but I don't need it to appear in every page in the application.
- I could insert it into the head, or add it to the document element, when the modal is loaded, using a JS function called by the modal contents.
- I could store it in the data tag of the Status display element.

Comment: If the JSON is going to be used by the modal dialog only, why need to put it elsewhere, i.e. out of the dialog? Or do you want to reuse it by other similar dialogs?

Comment: That's kind of what I'm asking - let's say I don't want it to load until it's needed; if it is applied to the page on the first modal dialog and it's used by all other dialogs, that's grand, but it could also be included only in the dialog and used only when that dialog is open. So where would the JSON be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where's the best place to put this JSON in the page, if it is loaded
>   with the modal contents?
>
> let's say I don't want it to load until it's needed; if it is applied
>   to the page on the first modal dialog and it's used by all other
>   dialogs, that's grand, but it could also be included only in the
>   dialog and used only when that dialog is open. So where would the JSON
>   be?

Well, keeping JSON data on a web page is easy. There is no need to think in terms of HTML elements as the bearers of data. You can just put it in the global object, `window`. Let's say you call the place to keep your data `VAULT`:

```
    // So, we have the JSON come from the sevrer side:
    var options = { "active": "Active", "removed", "Removed" };
    // Now, let's save it on the page:
    window.VAULT = {};
    VAULT.options = options;
```

Or put `options` in `window` directly (not recommended though because it might create mess in the global scope and cause collisions):

```
    window.modalOptions = options;
```

However, if you are loading your JSON with *every* AJAX request that loads your modal contents anyway, why put it anywhere outside the dialog? Just keep it within:

```
    // So, we have the JSON come from the server side:
    var options = { "active": "Active", "removed", "Removed" };

    // We have the dialog element (can be obtained in any other way):
    var dialog = document.getElementById('dialogId');

    // Now, just PUT the data in there:
    dialog.data = options;

    // Reuse it later:
    options = dialog.data;
```

Again, there is no need to use HTML elements' attributes to store data in your case. That technique is used to *deliver* data from the server side, but using it once data is already available only complicates things.

**UPDATE: Best practice for delivering JSON via AJAX**

**Short answer:** use JSON for the whole thing where keep the data and HTML markup separate.

**Full answer:**

Your server side responding for AJAX calls for the purpose of showing modal dialogs should return JSON where HTML markup should be kept separate from any other data. For example, the JSON returned could look like this:

```
    {
        "html": "<div>Dialog.. blablabla</div>",
        "data": {
            "options": { "active": "Active", "removed", "Removed" }
        }
    }
```

Your AJAX callback will need to be aware of the response structure to find and apply the HTML markup. The actual code will be different depending on whether/what JavaScript framework you are using, but roughly:

1. The response JSON will need to be parsed (typically done automatically with most modern JavaScript goodies):

   `var response = JSON.parse(responseText);`
2. The HTML markup will be available for applying to the modal dialog as:

   `response.html`
3. The `options` data (what constitutes "JSON" in your question) will be available as:

   `response.data.options`

Comment: Another good answer, I like the notion of storing the JSON against the element that will be using it (like the 'data' attribute suggestion from before). So in this case, it could be set to a "made up" property of the element (but not shown in HTML) by the JavaScript, but how is that called when the modal contents load? I suppose a call could be made to an arbitrary function in the modal contents on successful load, is there a better way?

Comment: I guess you already have a function that applies the loaded content to the dialog, don't you? You would also have some logic coded that will use the `options` data for applying to the Status display? So you just modify those bits of code so that they use the approach I showed in the answer.

Comment: I see where you're coming from and it's good, but it doesn't quite answer where the JSON would be. The JavaScript function for opening and populating the modal is in a separate .js file. So the JSON will have to be embedded in the HTML result called by the AJAX call. This is where I think the 'data attribute' answer makes sense.

Comment: Now I think I misunderstood your original question. I thought that embedding the JSON in the HTML result called by the AJAX call was a given thing — that was the way you were doing it, it was all settled and you were happy with it. And the question was where to keep the JSON hung around while the dialog is being worked with. Now, if you are asking how to *deliver* the JSON with the AJAX call, the answer would be different. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Apologies, but yeah, that's what I'm asking. In this case, what would be considered good practice?

Comment: That's a really great answer, very thorough and importantly maintains separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I would store this in the data attribute of an element that is associated with it given your description.

Example:

```
<div id="myelementid" data-status="@statusserverside" />
```

You could then populate this using Razor in the view from the back end.

This way it gets in the markup/page associated with that element and you have access to it from script easily.

Example: (jQuery but it is just an example)

```
var initialstatus = {
    "active": "Active",
        "removed": "Removed"
};
// push it in there
$('#myelementid').data("status", initialstatus);
// access it later
var status = $('#myelementid').data("status");
// access one property:
alert($('#myelementid').data("status").active);
// update one property
$('#myelementid').data("status").active = "FRED";
//list the properties(keys)
for (var key in status) {
    if (status.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        /* useful code here */
        alert(key + ":" + status.active + status[key]);
    }
}
```

PRACTICAL EXAMPLE:  Store a URL for your ajax in an element.

```
<div id="myfriend" data-url="@Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller")" ></div>
```

NOW the fun part: use this URL in an ajax call:

```
var myStoredUrl = $('#myfriend').data("url");
var myajax = $.ajax({
    url: myStoredUrl,
    //...other ajax stuff
});
myajax.done(function (data) {
//done stuff
});
```

Now if you refactor you don't have to remember the URL, the root etc. of the site to stick on the front, this does it for you.

Same net effect as your question (where to store stuff) just a different perspective that has worked well in production for me.

Comment: It's a good answer! My inclination was to store it in the element that would be using it. I hope you don't mind me not marking it as an answer yet because I want to see what other suggestions people have, and find out if there is a sort of best-practice for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the place to 'keep/store' the data would be in a view model. Then you would use something like angularS or knockout.js to bind the necessary DOM elements to their relative json datasets. If you want an example of this I can spin one up. If you want to go the traditional route, unless those datasets are dynamically changing, I'd say the best bet is to serve the page, then loop each dataset after document.ready() to keep your load times down.

It's kind of an open answer, where you'll have to choose what's best for your given scenario/needs.

Comment: Cheers for the answer, but I'm not using client-side MVC. Putting Angular or Knockout in for this would be total overkill!

Comment: what I meant was a View Model. You don't need a complex client side framework for this, you just want to keep separation of model from UI. It could be as simple as doing a $.get('MyViewModel.json', function(jsonData){ $('#myDialog').data = jsonData.whatever });

Comment: I understand what you mean now, it's a similar idea to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this particular case involves no JSON at all. I seem to have gotten it in my head that JSON (or something similar) would be necessary to provide the solution I needed, whereas there is a much simpler solution.

The *Status* property updates according to the settings applied through the date fields. A piece of JavaScript code would determine which of the date fields contains the most recent date, and set the status accordingly.

Solution: Store the Status string in the date picker controls.

In a Razor example, it might look like this:

```
<div class="date-picker" name="ActiveDate" data-status-name="@Enums.Status.Active.Description()" />
```

Thanks for all the answers, it's great to get some insight into possible ways to approach situations not just like this one.